# SMS retrieval api throws 6003 error in huawei mobile services

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

HMS SMS retrieval api throws 6003 error and broadcast receiver is getting triggered. I have checked hashcode and SMS format. Both are correct. Even broadcast receiver registered proper and sms listener registration is successful. Tried the same code in https://github.com/mudasirsharif/SmsRetrieverApi-HMS by upgrading gradle and agconnect. still no luck.

2023-04-09 18:06:50.078 8905-9098/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: in baseRequest + uri is :hwid.startSmsRetriever, transactionId is : 102182159riever20230409180650068745552
2023-04-09 18:06:50.084 8905-9098/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: init uri:hwid.startSmsRetriever
2023-04-09 18:06:50.088 8905-9098/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResultCallback
2023-04-09 18:06:50.166 8905-8941/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
2023-04-09 18:06:50.179 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
2023-04-09 18:06:50.182 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code6003, api_name:hwid.startSmsRetriever, app_id:102182159|, pkg_name:com.ubanquity.ahli_jo, session_id:*, transaction_id:102182159riever20230409180650068745552, resolution:null
2023-04-09 18:06:50.233 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo D/InputEventReceiver: dispatchInputInterval 0
2023-04-09 18:06:53.717 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/ViewRootImpl: dispatchDetachedFromWindow in doDie
2023-04-09 18:06:55.621 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode jank list is null
2023-04-09 18:06:58.638 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
2023-04-09 18:06:59.669 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo D/DecorView: showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023-04-09 18:07:02.803 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo D/DecorView: showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=true; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023-04-09 18:07:04.233 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo D/DecorView: showOrHideHighlightView: hasFocus=false; winMode=1; isMrgNull=true
2023-04-09 18:07:04.255 8905-8905/com.ubanquity.ahli_jo I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time

Answer (score 0):

6003 is the fingerprint verification error code. Its solution has been stated on Huawei Developers website like this:

> 1. Verify that the certificate fingerprint is correctly configured when you apply for related services.
>
> Android: Open the APK file of an app, extract the **META-INF**
> directory from the file, obtain the **CERT.RSA** file in the
> directory, and run the **keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA**
> command to record the signing certificate information.
>
> HarmonyOS: Decompress the HAP package at multiple levels to obtain the
> ***.EC** file in the **META-INF** directory. Then, run the following **keytool** command of the JDK to view the EC file: **keytool -printcert -file {File name}**
>
> 2. Sign in to AppGallery Connect, click **My projects**, and select a required project. On the displayed page, select the app, go to
>    **Project settings > General information**, and check whether the value in **SHA-256 certificate fingerprint** is the same as that in
>    step 1.

The above is quoted from [Huawei's documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hmscore-common-References/error-code-0000001050045846#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050045846__p158541021164)